# adding web image in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to add an image which is on the web with below code with pdfbox library.

```
  PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
  PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("https://XXXXXX.png",doc);
  PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
  contents.drawImage(pdImage, 70, 250);
```

With above code I get below error.

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!    at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(PDImageXObject.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFile(PDImageXObject.java:183)

But If I download this file in my local machine and then try with this code then it works fine.
Please let me know if I miss something.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK PDFBox does not support directly reading from HTTP etc (which makes sense - I wouldn't expect it to). You should download the file and either save it as a temporary file or write it to a byte-array. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).

Comment: Thanks for the response.